# Prevent swagger from merging similar regex mappings to a single operation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-codegen

An application I am working on has a `Controller` with mappings similar to my example below:

```java
@Api(tags = { "Some person API" })
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class SomeController {

    @ApiOperation(value = "GET person A or person B")
    @GetMapping("{person:A|B}")
    public void getPersonAorB(@PathVariable String person) {
        // Perform action with person
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "GET person C or person D")
    @GetMapping("{person:C|D}")
    public void getPersonCorD(@PathVariable String person) {
        // Perform action with person
    }
}
```

Although the endpoints work fine, Swagger does not distinguish between the endpoints `/person/{A|B}` and `/person/{C|D}`. As a result, Either the first or the second mapping is available in the OpenAPI documentation and in swagger UI.

I have tried several options to make Jenkins aware of the differences between the endpoints, such as adding `@Api` and `@ApiOperation` annotations to the mappings, however this did not succeed. I was able to fix the issue by creating a separate mapping for each endpoint, such as:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class SomeController {
    @GetMapping("A")
    public void getPersonA() {
        // Perform action with person "A"
    }
}
```

However I hope that there might be a better solution.

Comment: Not possible. In OpenAPI, the `/person/{foo}` and `/person/{bar}` paths are [considered identical](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.3.md#path-templating-matching).

Answer (score 0):

As it is the different endpoints , why same name for both.

```
@GetMapping("/personAorB/{id}")
public void getPersonAorB(@PathVariable String id) {
    // Perform action with person
}

@ApiOperation(value = "GET person C or person D")
@GetMapping("/personCorD/{id}")
public void getPersonCorD(@PathVariable String id) {
    // Perform action with person
}
```

If the endpoints are same , it will consider any one of the endpoint.